# Finding the necessary currents for AC analysis for CE NPN BJT amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

I have this circuit with a CE NPN-BJT amplifier and I am struggling to find the necessary values for calculating r(pi) for AC analysis, i.e. the hybrid-pi model:

$$r_{pi} = \frac{V_{thermal}}{I_b}$$

I need to find the current going into the base of the CE amplifier. I am assuming that the infinite capacitance to be short circuited in the DC analysis. This means that V(b) = 0 I can then use the active region model of NPN BJT for DC analysis to write down the KVL which gives me something like this: -0.7 - 60(I[e]) = 0

I solve the equation and end up with a negative emitter current. This does not adhere to the model. What am I doing wrong?

[[image: image_1]]

Comment: Even if your base capacitance is infinite, if you are running any simulation tool, at DC, all caps are considered open. Meaning in your case, that Vb is not 0.

Comment: @vtolentino No space before question mark!

Comment: @winny I didn't know about it. Is there any guideline written somewhere?

Comment: @vtolentino https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/qMarks.asp

Comment: @vtolentino As far as I'm aware, the only language that puts spaces before question marks is French. Every other language that uses question marks has them immediately following the last letter of the sentence.

Comment: For BJT Ie = Ib+Ic and in your circuit Ib + Ic = 0.5mA we can find \$r_{\pi}\$ using this equation \$r_{\pi} = (β +1) \times r_e\$ .where \$r_e = \frac{V_T}{I_E} ≈ \frac{26mV}{0.5mA} = 52Ω\$

Comment: @Hearth I never add space before the final punctuation. The reason I did so, is because I found other questions which had been edited the same way. Thanks though for pointing that out :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@vtolentino* already got it right in the comments: in DC analysis all capacitors are open-circuited, it should be fairly simple to find what you want after that.

I'd like to add that this BJT is not a *Common-Emitter* BJT, it's a *Common-Base* BJT because the base terminal is common to both inputs and outputs, so you're dealing with a **CB NPN-BJT**.